# Resources requirement for services

Tags: world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I'm trying to come up with a close to real costs when it comes to services for example counterfeiting a fake id, renting a room, hiring a cleaning personal etc. since some services would be out of their own skills or assets, the players would have to "rent" these services from other people. Is there any book that explains how much these services cost in terms of resource dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to fake IDS, the price varies awfully widely depending on how good it is and how deep it actually goes.

A standard fake license whose only purpose is to get you past a bouncer into the club? Without the magnetic strip? (Because these days, they can be scanned and checked against the actual system, or at least recorded)

For a not-so-great ID, without a readable strip: $50-100

The security measures we've got up the price. Faking the magnetic strip will cost a bit more--that's going to be $100-500. That price will depend on the rarity and complexity of the state's ID. I can say that in Florida at least, good luck buying booze at the supermarket without that strip. And even some of the clubs use a little hand-scanner now to run the card through. Even with the strip, if the cops stop you, it's not going to hold up if they actually run your id, just FYI.

An actual fake ID that also includes entries into data-bases and all that jazz, that--costs in the thousands. Establishing an actual identity is...tougher, especially these days.

Maids cost $25-45 an hour. Most people have them come in anywhere from once a week to once a month. An area less than 1,000 square feet averages $90 while 3,000 square feet or more could cost $250.

Most of the time you have to clean before the maid comes. I know that sounds weird, but they will clean, but they won't move a mess most of the time. Which seems counterintuitive. They just won't touch your stuff. A deep clean will cost more than the standard.

Renting a room--that's vague. It could be any room. A ballroom can cost you a grand...there's how much a flea bag motel is, and there's how much the Ritz is...

As far as I know there's no guide that explicitly covers every single thing in terms of resource dots, but it's not like you don't have some guidance. Once you determine the cost of the item, you can check it up against the resource chart. Rule I follow is this: how much is the item? Is it less than the disposable income? I subtract that from that month's disposable income. If they want to dip into assets to buy something, they will have to sell something.

> ● suggests low disposable income: $500 a month and approximately
>   $1,000 worth of assets.
>
> ●● suggest moderate disposable income: $1,000 a month and
>   approximately $5000 worth of assets.
>
> ●●● suggest significant disposable income: $2000 a month and maybe
>   $10,000 worth of assets.
>
> ●●●● suggest substantial disposable income: $10,000 a month and
>   $500,000 worth of assets.
>
> ●●●●● suggest significant wealth: $50,000 a month and as much as
>   $5,000,000 worth of assets. Resources can be used to determine if your
>   character can reasonably afford a purchase or expenditure.
>   **Equipment, weapons and items throughout these rules are assigned costs in dots. The Storyteller can assign cost dots to other items
>   during play based on what's here. If your character has the same or
>   more dots in Resources, he can afford the item on his disposable
>   income.** That doesn't mean he has a blank check with which to buy
>   everything he sees. **He might be able to afford one or two items with
>   a cost equal to his Resources dots in a single month.** Items with
>   lower costs can be acquired more often. The Storyteller has final say
>   on what's too much or what's too often.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unaware of any supplements that include such a mechanic.  It's highly subjective and situational.

As a Storyteller, I'd suggest making it an opposed roll between the seller and buyer of the service.  In the case of a Fake ID, I'd suggest either Wits+Rapport or Wits+Biz (or even a cross Attribute of Charisma+X) of the seller versus the Wits+Streetwise of the buyer.

Renting a room might be CHA+Business vs WIT+Business between the seller and buyer.  Set a base rate and modify it up or down by 5% per success on either side to simulate the "negotiation" of the fees.

Comment: The modifiers here are a nice touch. If they have underworld ties getting a fake ID is easy. I think Streetwise might be needed to even find a guy to do it and that will also maybe get you an idea of price. With Biz, it's hard to know the pricing for such a thing to even negotiate.  Renting a room, that's more in line with Biz--little things like knowing that hotel online cost --you can actually get a lower rate by calling because then they don't have to pay a cut to the online platform. Doesn't work for cheap ones...+1

Comment: Hotel rooms are very situational. They are willing to deal to fill the rooms more at the last minute AND if they are in the down season/there's no event or conference happening in town to push the prices up.

Comment: Thanks for the +1.  As a business traveler, I can definitely attest to how hotel prices can fluctuate.  I'm chuckling thinking of my players getting their characters signed up for Hilton Honors points to get the best deal, but it's not the craziest thing I've seen them do by a long shot!